# How do you use MBProgressHUD CustomView/Determinate Loader in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud

I am trying to run MBProgressHUD in Swift. I have found I am able to run a spinner that is very similar UIAlert spinner, but that I am having trouble with the other functions.  According the MBProgress docs, you can also user a determinate loader as well as other functions including a CustomView which could be loaded as a success.  I am trying to figure out how to load and access these other functions in Swift.

This is the current code for the indeterminate spinner  (the only function I can get working):

```
let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
loadingNotification.labelText = "Loading"
```

To dismiss the ProgressHUD:

```
MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
```

Please excuse such a simple question.  I am brand new to programming.  Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that one month later, you have solve it, but if not, I think this will work for you:

```
loadingNotification.hide(true)
```

Or with a delay:

```
loadingNotification.hide(true, afterDelay: 3)
```

Hope it helps! :)